# UrlFetchApp does not return any content

Tags: python, google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch

I am trying this basic **scraping** with google script:

```js
function getCourts() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://tennis.paris.fr/tennis/jsp/site/Portal.jsp?page=tennisParisien&view=les_tennis_parisiens");
  console.log('code', response.getResponseCode())
  console.log("content", response.getContentText())
}
```

but it returns an empty response:

```
11:18:21    Avis    Exécution démarrée
11:18:23    Infos   code 200
11:18:23    Infos   content 
11:18:23    Avis    Exécution terminée
```

Doing the same in python:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://tennis.paris.fr/tennis/jsp/site/Portal.jsp?page=tennisParisien&view=les_tennis_parisiens")
response.status_code
response.text
response.history
Out: [<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
```

I do have the content of the page and I see that it followed 4 redirects. Looking at the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) it says that `UrlFetchApp` also follows redirect though.

What am I missing?

PS:

```
curl https://tennis.paris.fr/tennis/jsp/site/Portal.jsp\?page\=tennisParisien\&view\=les_tennis_parisiens
```

does not return anything neither